# Azure for Web Apps - when I use Scale-Out, the total memory available also increases?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I've always assumed that if I had a 7gb of memory on my original instance, if increased one instance I would double the CPU and Memory available.

But when I do that, the Azure Monitoring Metrics keeps showing me the same percentage used (different from CPU)

The thing is, I would like to "Scale-down" my instance to 3.5Gb and use AutoScale to increase it whenever necessary, but with 7gb I'm already reaching 45% of memory on high demand hours.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Scale out is instance duplication. Scale up is instance specification increases:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-scale-up